# Why does the following ReaderT String IO lose an IO action?

Tags: haskell

```
module Main (main) where

import Control.Monad.Reader

p1 :: String -> IO ()
p1 = putStrLn . ("Apple "++)

p2 :: String -> IO ()
p2 = putStrLn . ("Pear "++)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    p1 "x"
    p2 "y"
    r "z"

r :: String -> IO ()
r = do
    p1
    p2
```

It prints:

Apple x
Pear y
Pear z

Why?

Comment: Thank you for the insightful answers. It seems I assumed that there would be a `ReaderT r m` instance for `r -> m a`, but apparently there isn't.

Comment: `ReaderT` is a type, not a class -- so there can't be instances of it!

Comment: Daniel: Indeed, sorry. Is it possible to make a `Monad` instance for `(r -> m a)` and then define a `MonadReader` instance for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in `r`. Given the following definition of `Reader` monad:

```
instance Monad ((->) e) where
    return = const
    f >>= g = \x -> g (f x) x
```

We can simplify `r`:

```
r = p1 >> p2    
  = (>>=) p1 (\_ -> p2)    
  = (\f g x -> g (f x) x) p1 (\_ -> p2)    
  = \x -> (\_ -> p2) (p1 x) x    
  = \x -> p2 x
```

This also shows that `Reader`'s `(>>)` is just `const` with a bit more specific type.

If you want to distribute the environment and then execute both actions, you have to bind the result of applying `p1` to the environment, for example:

```
r = do a1 <- p1
       a2 <- p2
       return (a1 >> a2)
```

Or using `Applicative`:

```
r = (>>) <$> p1 <*> p2
```

---

Expanding on the `Reader` part, `Control.Monad.Reader` provides three variants of `Reader`.

- the implicit `(->) e`, which is what the function `r` uses
- the monad transformer `ReaderT e m`, a newtype wrapper for functions of type `e -> m a`
- the explicit `Reader e`, defined in terms of `ReaderT` as `ReaderT e Identity`

Without any further information, the implicit `(->) e` will be used. Why?

The overall type of `do` block is given by the last expression, which is also constrained to be of the form `Monad m => m a` for some `m` and `a`.

Looking back at `r`, it's clear that the `do` block has a type `String -> IO ()` as given by the type of `r` and also `p2`. It also requires `String -> IO ()` to be `Monad m => m a`. Now, unifying these two types:

```
m = (->) String
a = IO ()
```

This matches `(->) e` monad instance by choosing `e = String`.

---

Being a monad transformer, `ReaderT` takes care of the inner plumbing to make sure the actions of the inner monad are properly sequenced and executed. To select `ReaderT`, it is necessary to explicitly mention it (usually in a type signature, but functions which fix the type to be `ReaderT`, such as `runReaderT`, also work):

```
r :: ReaderT String IO ()
r = do ? p1
       ? p2

r' :: String -> IO ()
r' = runReaderT r
```

This comes with another problem, `p1` and `p2` have a type `String -> IO ()`, which doesn't match the required `ReaderT String IO ()`.

The ad-hoc solution (tailored exactly for this situation), is just to apply

```
ReaderT :: (e -> m a) -> ReaderT e m a
```

To obtain something more general, `MonadIO` type class can lift `IO` actions into the transformer and `MonadReader` type class allows accessing the environment. These two type classes work as long as there is `IO` (or `ReaderT` respectively) somewhere in the transformer stack.

```
lift' :: (MonadIO m, MonadReader a m) => (a -> IO b) -> m b
lift' f = do
    env <- ask     -- get environment
    let io = f env -- apply f to get the IO action
    liftIO io      -- lift IO action into transformer stack
```

Or more concisely:

```
lift' f = ask >>= liftIO . f
```

---

Regarding your question in comments, you can implement the relevant instances in this way:

```
newtype ReaderT e m a = ReaderT { runReaderT :: e -> m a }

instance Monad m => Monad (ReaderT e m) where
    return  = ReaderT . const . return
      -- The transformers package defines it as "lift . return".
      -- These two definitions are equivalent, though.
    m >>= f = ReaderT $ \e -> do
        a <- runReaderT m e
        runReaderT (f a) e

instance Monad m => MonadReader e (ReaderT e m) where
    ask        = ReaderT return
    local  f m = ReaderT $ runReaderT m . f
    reader f   = ReaderT (return . f)
```

The actual typeclass can be found in the `mtl` package ([package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.1.2), [type class](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/2.1.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Reader.html)), the newtype and `Monad` instance in `transformers` package ([package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0), [type class](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/0.3.0.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html)).

---

As for making a `e -> m a` `Monad` instance, you are out of luck. `Monad` requires a type constructor of kind `* -> *`, which means we are attempting to do something like this (in pseudo-code):

```
instance Monad m => Monad (/\a -> e -> m a) where
    -- ...
```

where `/\` stands for type-level lambda. However, the closest thing we can get to a type level lambda is a type synonym (which must be fully applied before we can make type class instances, so no luck here) or a type family (which cannot be used as an argument to type class either). Using something like `(->) e . m` leads to `newtype` again.

Answer (score 2):

Let's first rewrite the body of

```
r :: String -> IO ()
r = do
    p1
    p2
```

using `(>>)`,

```
r = p1 >> p2
```

so `p1` must have type `m a` for some `Monad` `m`, and `p2` must have type `m b` for the same `m`.

Now,

```
p1, p2 :: String -> IO ()
```

and the top-level type constructor in that is the function arrow `(->)`. Therefore the `Monad` used in `r` must be

```
(->) String
```

The `Monad` instance for `(->) e` [aka the reader monad], is

```
instance Monad ((->) e) where
    -- return :: a -> (e -> a)
    return = const
    -- (>>=) :: (e -> a) -> (a -> (e -> b)) -> (e -> b)
    f >>= g = \x -> g (f x) x
```

and consequently,

```
p1 >> p2 = p1 >>= \_ -> p2
         = \x -> (\_ -> p2) (p1 x) x   -- apply (\_ -> p2) to (p1 x)
         = \x -> p2 x                  -- eta-reduce
         = p2
```

so that was just a complicated way to write

```
r = p2
```

Answer (score 2):

For `r` you used `(->) String (IO ())`  which is a `Monad ((->) String)` that returns a value of type `IO ()`.

You did NOT use a `ReaderT` or any monad transformer.  You used a monad that returns a different monad.  It accidentally compiled and ran, almost doing what you expected.

You need to use `runReaderT` and `lift` (or `liftIO`) to achieve the `r` that I think you are trying to make.

Comment: True, `r = runReaderT $ ReaderT p1 >> ReaderT p2` solves it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You left off the argument when you invoke p1 and p2 in r. What you wrote is then interpreted as pointfree notation, so only the second IO action gets an argument. This works:

```
r :: String -> IO ()
r x = do
    p1 x
    p2 x
```

To understand why this is happening, consider that what you originally wrote is equivalent to

```
r = p1 >> p2
```

The compiler interprets that as something like

```
r x = (p1 >> p2) x
```

Which isn't what you want.

Comment: That is what I wanted, however it seems I missed the ReaderT part.